# How to update props when switching between child components

Tags: reactjs, components

Currently I am working on project where we are working on the transition from AngularJs to React, but I am come a cross a problem which I am unable to solve. The problem is as follows:

I have parent component which shows all the users. The parent component refers to multiple child components (edit user, orders of user, activity of the user, etc), but when I change the between users the props in the child component hasn't changed and it still shows the previous user.

Example.

Click on User A - click on edit user (works fine).

Click on User B - click on edit user (shows props from User A).

I have looked at the documentation, but I am unable to find a suitable solution. I cam across the following article from the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component

It says that a possible solution is to at a key to your component. The props will update when the key has updated. This solution would have worked if I only had 1 child component. Unfortunately this is not the case.

This is the code for the child components:

```
{isSelected ? <IndividualModalComponent onClose={() => setShowEditDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showEditDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
{isSelected ? <IndividualSecurityComponent onClose={() => setShowPermissionDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showPermissionDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
{isSelected ? <IndividualPasswordComponent onClose={() => setShowPasswordDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showPasswordDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
{isSelected ? <IndividualTwoFactorComponent onClose={() => setShowTwoFactorDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showTwoFactorDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
{isSelected ? <IndividualSessionComponent onClose={() => setShowSessionDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showSessionDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
{isSelected ? <IndividualOrderComponent onClose={() => setShowOrderDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showOrderDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/> : null}
```

When using the code shown above I am getting the following error:

```
backend.js:6 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `48097be2-84c2-4a29-acdc-87e57ba88428`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behaviour is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

This is because I use the same key for multiple components.

I would like to be able to switch between users where the props also change. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you update the user in the child component? Can you provide an example e.g. IndividualSecurityComponent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, put the **selectedIndividual** in the state, and when you click on edit user, update the **selectedIndividual** state to match the user that you clicked and in that case, the props from all the children should be updated directly.

If you put the **individual** props of any child in the child's state, you should update that once the props has changed. One way to solve this is by implementing [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Second way is to update the key props of the children. Third way is implementing [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

To resolve the error in the console with regards to the key, I suggest you put a different prefix in every child, for example:

```
<IndividualModalComponent key={`modal${selectedIndividual.id}`} {...otherProps} />
<IndividualSecurityComponent key={`security${selectedIndividual.id}`} {...otherProps} />
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The {`modal${selectedIndividual.id}`} did the trick. Thank you. I already put the selectedIndividual in the state.

Comment: Happy to help! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is something like

```
{isSelected && (
    <>
        <IndividualModalComponent onClose={() => setShowEditDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showEditDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
        <IndividualSecurityComponent onClose={() => setShowPermissionDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showPermissionDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
        <IndividualPasswordComponent onClose={() => setShowPasswordDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showPasswordDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
        <IndividualTwoFactorComponent onClose={() => setShowTwoFactorDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showTwoFactorDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
        <IndividualSessionComponent onClose={() => setShowSessionDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showSessionDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
        <IndividualOrderComponent onClose={() => setShowOrderDialog(false)} isDialogOpen={showOrderDial} key={selectedIndividual.id} individual={selectedIndividual}/>
    </>
)}
```

Comment: This would improve the readability of this code, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the data is not changing the child props is not changing. you need to provide a state for the parent that change on click to make re-render your child component. 
this sandbox show same concept you trying to achieve: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-brattain-cf9nm)